# Is every production in a CFG an $A$-production?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

In Ullman's Introduction to Automata, Languages and Computation (1979):

> A context-free grammar (CFG or just grammar) is denoted $G = (V, T, P, S)$, where
> $V$ and $T$ are finite sets of variables and terminals, respectively. We assume that $V$
> and $T$ are disjoint. $P$ is a finite set of productions; **each production is of the form
> $A\to \alpha$**, where $A$ is a variable and $\alpha$ is a string of symbols from $(V \cup T)^*$.

> Lemma 43 Define **an $A$-production** to be a production with variable $A$ on the
> left. Let $G = (V, T, P, S)$ be a CFG....

Is an $A$-production defined as a production $A\to \alpha$, where $A$ is a variable and $\alpha$ is a  string of symbols from $(V \cup T)^*$?

Is every production in a CFG an $A$-production?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. The $A$-*productions* defined in **Lemma** $\mathbf{4.3}$ are specifically those productions that have the variable $A$ on the lefthand side. In that terminology a production $B\to\beta$ would be a $B$-production. If you look at the second paragraph of the proof of **Theorem** $\mathbf{4.6}$, you’ll see this usage: the authors talk about ‘each $A_j$-production’ in a context in which they are clearly referring to productions with $A_j$ on the lefthand side.